# Respond to External IVT from Twilio

Tags: javascript, twilio, ivr

I've setup a simple call center using Twilio JavaScript library. I want to know how we can respond by key press when we call to external IVR systems. I found and following Twilio documentation of implementing our own IVR with Twilio Studio. But what I need here is as a client how we can respond to external IVR systems by pressing '1' for Sales, '2' for promotions, etc. ?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can play DTMF tones using Twilio in two ways.

You can either do so at the start of creating a call by sending the `SendDigits` parameter with the digits you want to send (and `w`s for 0.5s pauses). For example:

```
client.calls
  .create({
     url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
     to: '+15558675310',
     from: '+15017122661',
     sendDigits: 'wwww194'
   })
```

Will create a call, when the call connects it will wait 2 seconds (4 * w == 4 * 0.5s) and then send the tones for 194.

Alternatively, if you are in the middle of a call you can respond to questions using DTMF tones with the [`<Play>` TwiML element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) using the [`digits` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#attributes-digits), like this:

```
const response = new VoiceResponse();
response.play({
    digits: 'wwww194'
});
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I was thinking to go with `sendDigits` at the time I trigger the TwiML. Looks like the second option is the real user experience as we can't pre-define numbers to be keyed. Do we have the same functionality in JavaScript API too here https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/overview ?

Comment: Oh, yeah, if you're doing it on a client call then you want to use the [`Twilio.Device#sendDigits` method](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#sendDigits).

Comment: Ahh, so if I have the active connection object, I can simply respond with `conn.sendDigits('wwww194');` it seems?

Comment: Bah, yes, it's the connection, not the device (and I can't edit my comment now). But yes, that is what you would do!

Comment: Superb! I'll try this out, interesting!

Comment: I tried executing `connection.sednDigits('www1');` upon dialpad button click after hearing the IVR recording. But getting "Cannot read property 'play' of undefined at playNextDigit". Any idea? I'm using v1.4 and `connection` I'm setting at the time of making the call. i.e. `connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);`

Comment: Ok, simply upgrading my twilio.min.js to version v1.6 now it's working. Anyway appreciate your confirmation on this.